# Case-insensitive Custom Setting value in Trigger

Tags: apex, trigger

I have a Trigger that is referencing a field (BillingCountry) and validating against a Custom Setting table (ISOCountry__c). The reference is case-sensitive and I would like to make it case-insensitive.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Trigger:

```
trigger UpdateISOCodeAccount on Account (before insert, before update) {

Map<String, ISOCountry__c> isoCountryMap = ISOCountry__c.getAll();

for(Account a :trigger.new){

    if(isoCountryMap.containsKey(a.BillingCountry))
        a.Billing_Country_Code_2__c = isoCountryMap.get(a.BillingCountry).Country_ISO2_Code__c;
    else a.Billing_Country_Code_2__c= '-';
    if(a.BillingCountry == NULL) {a.Billing_Country_Code_2__c = 'NULL';}
    }
}
```

Comment: Just store them lower case and then call `toLowerCase` before `getInstance`.

Comment: use containsIgnoreCase string method

Comment: @ShravanBoddula there's not `getIgnoreCase`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a lot of help from **Adrian Larson** we came to a workable solution with my initial Trigger issue.

I will post the trigger in its current state, however with the knowledge that **the trigger now has logic inline (bad practice)** which should really be in a TriggerHandler class (something for another day).

Firstly the custom setting has been modified to be in lower case, then...

```
trigger UpdateISOCodeAccount on Account (before insert, before update) {

for(Account a :trigger.new){

    String bCountry = a.BillingCountry;
    if (bCountry != null) bCountry = bCountry.toLowerCase();

    ISOCountry__c bsetting = ISOCountry__c.getInstance(bCountry);

    if (bsetting != null) a.Billing_Country_Code_2__c = bsetting.Country_ISO2_Code__c;
    else a.Billing_Country_Code_2__c= '-';
    if(bCountry == NULL) {a.Billing_Country_Code_2__c = 'NULL';}

    }
}
```

Cheers!

Comment: Just fyi, when an answer [addresses your problem](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers), etiquette is generally to [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234) by clicking on the check mark/tick to the left of the answer, turning it green. This marks the question as resolved to your satisfaction, and awards [reputation](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) both to you and the person who answered. If you have >= 15 reputation points, you may also upvote the answer if you wish. There is no obligation to do either.

Answer (score 2):

You can store and retrieve the data in lower case if you wish to make the mapping case-insensitive:

```
public class ISOCodes
{
    public ISOCountry__c get(String isoCode)
    {
        return (isoCode == null) ? null : settings.get(isoCode.toLowerCase());
    }
    static Map<String, ISOCountry__c> settings
    {
        get
        {
            if (settings == null)
            {
                settings = new Map<String, ISOCountry>();
                for (ISOCountry__c setting : ISOCountry__c.getAll().values())
                    settings.put(setting.toLowerCase(), setting);
            }
            return settings;
        }
        private set;
    }
}
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49812/discussion-between-adrian-larson-and-themikeyboosh).